# Compile project that uses many modules

Tags: swift, module, compilation, frameworks

I'm writing an app that is divided into frameworks. I would like the Xcode to compile all modules at once (whenever needed) when I'm trying to build main project target. Unfortunately when I press "play" I get an error like:

```
Header 'Observation-Swift.h' not found
module.modulemap
```

and

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'Observation'
World.swift
```

All targets are written in swift, so Objective-C is a mistake.

The only way to make this compile is to compile all targets one by one. Is there some way to make all targets compile automatically? Also there are some dependencies between targets.

```
WebService imports Observation
World imports Observation and BackgroundTask
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I needed to select every target that have dependencies and add used frameworks under "Linked Framweorks and Libraries". Then Xcode knows in what order to compile frameworks and it works.